# Turn CLOB data column into string

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I have the below query and I receive the below error. 
I only needs the first 4000 characters. Any idea on how to solve this?

`ora-00406 compatible paramerter needs to be 12.0 or greater`

```
create or replace for editionable view vw_fnds
select
A.id,
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(A.FINDINGS,4000,1) --clob data type
from tableA
```

Comment: what did you try? a simple g00gle search tells me: database [compatibility mode](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00406_compatible_parameter_needs.htm). *Action: Shutdown and startup with a higher compatibility setting.*

Comment: I don't have the ability to shutdown and startup with higher compatibility settings.

Comment: or a [broken installation](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3804232): execute `SHOW PARAMETERS COMPATIBLE` as dba, if this gets you 12c its probably in an invalid state, if its lower, its in the middle of an upgrade.

Comment: Try casting the value in the Clob column instead.
(eg: CAST(A.FINDINGS AS VARCHAR2(4000))